# How do I know if Qt links against openssl, and which one?

Tags: qt, openssl

Looking at the libs (`:/Qt/5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib/`) of Qt5.11.0, I was wondering which one was linking openssl. So I ran the following:

```
for lib in `ls *.so`; do ldd $lib | grep ssl; done
```

And I got no output, suggesting that none of the libraries are linking against openssl. But I believe that Qt must link against it somehow (e.g. for networking).

How is the linking done? And where does it look for openssl? Do I have a way to know which one Qt found on my system (e.g. given I have multiple ones)?

Comment: IIRC it should be in QtNetwork, but it may be linked statically, depending from how Qt was built.

Comment: Coming to think about it, I vaguely remember that there was a complicated system of stubs to actually load openssl dynamically at runtime (i.e. explicitly using `dlopen`); you should probably check the diagnostic output of the dynamic linker to debug this.

Comment: So Qt comes from the Qt GUI installer. I have heard of their system (I think it is related to `qt.conf`), but I don't understand how that works. I'll try to check with the diagnostic output of the dynamic linker if I manage to see if my app links against openssl at runtime. But I still would like to understand how Qt finds the library (even if it is done at runtime)...

Comment: Qt loads dynamically OpenSSL library at run-time unless you build Qt from sources and give configure the option -openssl-linked.

Comment: Right. And how does it find the OpenSSL library, then? Say I have two of them installed on the system... does it take the first one in the path, or can I configure that somehow (e.g. some `qt.conf` file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt links some libraries dynamically at runtime. In order to see which libraries are loaded, one can check the diagnostic output of the dynamic linker, as hinted by Matteo:

Say my executable is called `QGroundcontrol`:

On Linux:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs ./QGroundcontrol 2>&1 | grep -E "ssl|crypto"
```

On macOS:

```
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 ./QGroundcontrol 2>&1 | grep -E "ssl|crypto"
```

From this I could see that Qt finds openssl on the system.

Now, I still don't know how I can tell Qt to look somewhere else (in case I want to link another openssl), but [that's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521213/how-can-i-tell-qt-where-it-should-look-for-openssl).