# How can I tell Qt where it should look for openssl?

Tags: qt, openssl

Qt seems to load openssl dynamically at runtime, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508676/how-do-i-know-if-qt-links-against-openssl-and-which-one/51521160#51521160).

And apparently, it gets the system openssl. For instance, on macOS, I would rather use the homebrew-installed openssl, and package it into my dmg, so that the users don't need to install it themselves.

How can I tell Qt where to look for the libraries it links? Is there something to do with the `qt.conf` file?

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable?

Comment: Is it what Qt is using to find libraries on macOS?

Comment: According to http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html this mechanism is common for all shared libraries (Linux), no only for Qt ones.

Comment: But then it means that I should tell the users of my software to edit LD_LIBRARY_PATH before they start it. Or I should provide a script that does it. It doesn't seem very clean, right?

I find it weird that apparently, most developers use the homebrew-installed openssl, but with Qt you can't do it without rebuilding Qt or changing environment variables =/.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that in your .pro file:

```
win32-msvc* {
    LIBS += -LC:/openssl/lib/ -llibeay32
    LIBS += -LC:/openssl/lib/ -lssleay32

    INCLUDEPATH += C:/openssl/include
}
```

left click on your project -> add library -> external library -> choose the .lib file and the include folder for the library. check for which platform it is.
It will put the specific platform dependend commands to your project .pro filefile.